# Datamapper's analog to find_by_ method

Tags: activerecord, sinatra, datamapper

Is there any analog to ActiveRecord's find_by_  method in Datamapper
ex: `@user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [datamapper documentation](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html) and the way I do it, you can do:

```
@user = User.first(:email => params[email]) #strictly the same as find_by_email in Activerecord
@user = User.all(:email => params[email]) #strictly the same as find_all_by_email in Activerecord
@user = User.last(:email => params[email]) #no real equivalent in Active Record
```

Comment: Thanks! If I understood right if there is no record it just returns nil

Comment: You could go for `#first_or_create`, if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @user1136228 yes as far as I remember.